# phonegap icon not working on iPhone

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, config, iconv

I am creating a phonegap app... I see the app icon in the simulator and then when i put it on my actual iPhone, I see the PG Build App icon.. My ipa is named PG Build App. How do I get the app icon to change on my actual phone?

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.bolton.chris" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>KMtoMiles</name>
<description>
    Converts Kilometers to Miles
</description>
<author>
    Chris Bolton
</author>
<icon src="Resources/icons/running.png" platform="ios"/>
<splash src="www/img/nature_background.jpg" platform="ios"/>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this issue previously . My xml changes not reflected to the new build . The easy solution is the go to the resource folder of from where the default phone gap actually takes the icons . And then replace those with your icons . for the best result rename your icons with default phone gap icons.

Comment: So this worked.. But I need my images to be the same size as the default icons... What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @ChrisBolton: I dont thing I understood . but you can adjust size from the preview

Comment: have  a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html also you can check the icons sizes given by default by phone gap .